# Control Battery Thresholds on X1 Carbon 4th Gen

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery, thinkpad

I've been using the [tlp](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) utility for optimizing my battery settings on a ThinkPad 4th generation X1 Carbon running Ubuntu 16.04.  I would like to set charging thresholds as follows:

```
$ sudo tlp setcharge 75 80
Error: ThinkPad extended battery functions not available.
```

Looking through the documentation it recommends installing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms
```

Which I've already done.  It also recommends looking at the recommendations under `tlp-stat`

```
+++ ThinkPad Extended Battery Functions
tp-smapi   = inactive (kernel module 'tp_smapi' load error)
tpacpi-bat = inactive (kernel module 'acpi_call' load error)
```

Perhaps hardware has changed?  How can I further diagnose my problem?  Are there alternatives that work for the hardware within the 4th gen X1 Carbon?

### Update

Secure boot was still active.  Going through the instructions below from @linrunner and also removing Secure UEFI Boot were sufficient to resolve the problem.  It may have been that things would have been fine with just the secure boot change though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install TLP 0.9 from the PPA for better diagnostics on kernel modules.
2. You may uninstall the **tp-smapi-dkms** package. tp-smapi is not supported on your hardware (0.9 will tell you this).
3. See the [FAQ](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#battery) how to load the acpi-call module manually and check the output for errors (add output to your question)
4. When 3. is unsuccessful try to reinstall the package, check (and add) the output too:

   sudo apt-get install --reinstall acpi-call-dkms